# How to return the value of a HashMap

Tags: java

Let's say we have our map

```
private Map<TeamType, Player> teamPlayers = new HashMap<>();
```

and we initialize them

```
teamPlayers.put(TeamType.ONE, new ArrayList<Player>());
teamPlayers.put(TeamType.TWO, new ArrayList<Player>());
```

and we store some values in them

```
teamPlayers.get(TeamType.ONE).add(player);
teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TWO).add(player);
```

is there a way to return the amount of players in both teams besides doing

```
int totalPlayers = teamPlayers.get(TeamType.ONE).size() + teamPlayers.get(TeamType.Two).size();
```

because this can get very cluttered after having more then 4 teams. Keep in mind TeamType is an enum.

Comment: Let's say I have 4 shelves. The first shelf supports 1 book, the second shelf supports 3 books, the third shelf supports 5 books, and the fourth shelf supports 2 books. How would you count the total number of supported books across all shelves?

Comment: So you have a map like this `Map<TeamType, Player>` and then the value is of type list? Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
 int total =teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TEAM_ONE).size() + teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TEAM_TWO).size()
```

should work. Instead of referencing your old post can you post your current code? hard to know what changes youve made and what suggestions you took from the last post.

updated answer for iterating through every entry in your TeamType enum:

```
int total = 0;
for(TeamType type : TeamType.values()){
    total += teamPlayers.get(type).size();
}
```

so the for each loop will iterate through each entry in your enum, and total will accumulate the number of players for each team

Comment: teamPlayers.get(TeamType.TEAM_ONE) would return a Player and it makes sense that you wont be able to call size() on a Player

Comment: well he references his last post which provides an accepted answer to use a list of players instead of only one player which is part of the reason i requested that he posted his current code. Hard to tell what OP is doing without any code

Comment: @peggy I am sorry guys. Did not see that!!

Comment: @Vwin no problem at all.

Comment: The answer is correct. :)

Comment: Nah what Vwin stated works if you make it teamPlayers.get(...).size() but what if we had lets say 10 teams, doing it like that will get it very cluttered..

Comment: Yes you need to iterate through the map

Comment: @peggy i've done it.

Comment: ok so you are using lists, so iterate through all of your teams and add their sizes as shown above

Comment: @peggy can you show an example.. as shown above means nothing because nobody has yet posted an answer to my problem :/

Comment: updated my answer. and if you were to post clear questions which include your code from the beginning, we couldve gotten here a lot faster :) all is good though welcome to Stack Overflow :D

Comment: I wonder what will happen if there are four possible teams in the enum, but only  two team play in a given game ... maybe a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: my understanding is he does not want to count the players that exist in a game, but all players from all teams

Comment: Well, then let's hope so.

Comment: @peggy isn't there a way to make it a one liner with a lambda? Wouldn't

'code'public static Optional<TeamType> getCount() {
return Arrays.stream(values()).....
}'code'